# Counting NA as a factor within each variable

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have code that counts the frequency of a value, by group (see below).

```
 mtcars$disp[4:9]<-NA
    mtcars$hp[9:12]<-NA
    mtcars$mpg[10:12] <- NA

    varList <- 2:4
    lapply(varList,function(x,df,byVar){ 
             tabular((Factor(df[[x]],paste(colnames(df)[x])) + 1) ~ ((Factor(df[[byVar]],paste(byVar)))*((n=1) + Percent("col"))),
                 data= df) 
      },mtcars,"cyl")
```

I would like to adjust the code so that it also counts the number of NA's within each variable as well.

So for example, if there were missing in region it would show up like this in my output: There are no NA's in region actually so this data is fake.

```
           sexe                                
                            F            M           O          
 region                     n    Percent n   Percent n   Percent
 Alsace                       6    3.922   3   1.515   6   3.704
 Aquitaine                    0    0.000   6   3.030   6   3.704
 Auvergne                     6    3.922   6   3.030   3   1.852
 Bourgogne                    3    1.961   3   1.515   0   0.000
 Bretagne                     3    1.961   0   0.000  12   7.407
 Centre                      15    9.804  21  10.606  21  12.963
 Champagne-Ardenne            3    1.961   0   0.000   6   3.704
 Corse                        6    3.922   9   4.545   3   1.852
 Franche-Comté                9    5.882  15   7.576  12   7.407
 Haute-Normandie              3    1.961   0   0.000   0   0.000
 Île-de-France                0    0.000   0   0.000   0   0.000
 Languedoc-Roussillon         6    3.922  15   7.576   3   1.852
 Lorraine                     3    1.961   6   3.030   0   0.000
 Midi-Pyrénées               15    9.804   0   0.000   0   0.000
 Nord-Pas-de-Calais           3    1.961   9   4.545   6   3.704
 Pays de la Loire             0    0.000   0   0.000   3   1.852
 Picardie                     6    3.922   9   4.545  12   7.407
 Poitou-Charentes            12    7.843   6   3.030  12   7.407
 Provence-Alpes-Côte d'Azur   6    3.922   0   0.000   3   1.852
 Rhône-Alpes                 12    7.843  30  15.152  15   9.259
 **NA                          5     4.6    5    5       5    5**
 All                        153  100.000 198 100.000 162 100.000
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @Len Greski I've adapted your answer...

Comment: Is there any other packages involved inaddition to fakir

Comment: @akrun nope, but I added an example with mtcars!

Comment: there is a `tabular` function.  Is it from tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `tables` package, an option is to convert to `factor` with `exclude = NULL`

```
library(tables)
mtcars$cyl[4:7] <- NA
mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl, exclude =NULL )
```

-running the OP's code

```
varList <- 2:4
lapply(varList,function(x,df,byVar){ 
          tabular((Factor(df[[x]],paste(colnames(df)[x])) + 1) ~ ((Factor(df[[byVar]],paste(byVar)))*((n=1) + Percent("col"))),
              data= df) 
   },mtcars,"cyl")
#[[1]]
                                                
#     cyl                                        
#     4           6         8          NA        
# cyl n   Percent n Percent n  Percent n  Percent
# 4   11  100     0   0      0   0     0    0    
# 6    0    0     5 100      0   0     0    0    
# 8    0    0     0   0     12 100     0    0    
# NA   0    0     0   0      0   0     4  100    
# All 11  100     5 100     12 100     4  100    

#[[2]]
                                                  
#       cyl                                        
#       4           6         8          NA        
# disp  n   Percent n Percent n  Percent n  Percent
# 71.1   1    9.091 0   0      0   0.000 0    0    
# 75.7   1    9.091 0   0      0   0.000 0    0    
# 78.7   1    9.091 0   0      0   0.000 0    0    
# 79     1    9.091 0   0      0   0.000 0    0    
# 95.1   1    9.091 0   0      0   0.000 0    0    
# 108    1    9.091 0   0      0   0.000 0    0    
# 120.1  1    9.091 0   0      0   0.000 0    0    
# 120.3  1    9.091 0   0      0   0.000 0    0    
# 121    1    9.091 0   0      0   0.000 0    0    
# 140.8  1    9.091 0   0      0   0.000 0    0    
# 145    0    0.000 1  20      0   0.000 0    0    
# 146.7  1    9.091 0   0      0   0.000 0    0    
# 160    0    0.000 2  40      0   0.000 0    0    
# 167.6  0    0.000 2  40      0   0.000 0    0    
# 225    0    0.000 0   0      0   0.000 1   25    
# 258    0    0.000 0   0      0   0.000 1   25    
# 275.8  0    0.000 0   0      3  25.000 0    0    
# 301    0    0.000 0   0      1   8.333 0    0    
# 304    0    0.000 0   0      1   8.333 0    0    
# 318    0    0.000 0   0      1   8.333 0    0    
# 350    0    0.000 0   0      1   8.333 0    0    
# 351    0    0.000 0   0      1   8.333 0    0    
# 360    0    0.000 0   0      0   0.000 2   50    
# 400    0    0.000 0   0      1   8.333 0    0    
# 440    0    0.000 0   0      1   8.333 0    0    
# 460    0    0.000 0   0      1   8.333 0    0    
# 472    0    0.000 0   0      1   8.333 0    0    
# All   11  100.000 5 100     12 100.000 4  100    

#[[3]]
                                                
#     cyl                                        
#     4           6         8          NA        
# hp  n   Percent n Percent n  Percent n  Percent
# 52   1    9.091 0   0      0   0.000 0    0    
# 62   1    9.091 0   0      0   0.000 0    0    
# 65   1    9.091 0   0      0   0.000 0    0    
# 66   2   18.182 0   0      0   0.000 0    0    
# 91   1    9.091 0   0      0   0.000 0    0    
# 93   1    9.091 0   0      0   0.000 0    0    
# 95   1    9.091 0   0      0   0.000 0    0    
# 97   1    9.091 0   0      0   0.000 0    0    
# 105  0    0.000 0   0      0   0.000 1   25    
# 109  1    9.091 0   0      0   0.000 0    0    
# 110  0    0.000 2  40      0   0.000 1   25    
# 113  1    9.091 0   0      0   0.000 0    0    
# 123  0    0.000 2  40      0   0.000 0    0    
# 150  0    0.000 0   0      2  16.667 0    0    
# 175  0    0.000 1  20      1   8.333 1   25    
# 180  0    0.000 0   0      3  25.000 0    0    
# 205  0    0.000 0   0      1   8.333 0    0    
# 215  0    0.000 0   0      1   8.333 0    0    
# 230  0    0.000 0   0      1   8.333 0    0    
# 245  0    0.000 0   0      1   8.333 1   25    
# 264  0    0.000 0   0      1   8.333 0    0    
# 335  0    0.000 0   0      1   8.333 0    0    
# All 11  100.000 5 100     12 100.000 4  100
```

---

If we need the columns 2 to 4 `NA` values to be excluded, then convert to `factor` and use `exclude = NULL`

```
mtcars[varList] <- lapply(mtcars[varList], factor, exclude = NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks! It's not quite what I mean. In my data cyl has complete values, but hp, disp etc, has missing values. So I want the count of each NA within those variables, will update my example to make this clear.

Comment: @NewBee In that case, you need the `hp` `disp` etc factor with `exclude = NULL`